# Tooltip on inline images in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, image-mode, inline-image

Is it possible to make this kind of an inline image link:

```
[[path/to/the/image/of/a/cat][fluffy]]
```

appear as an inline image in org-mode, and if you hover over it, you can see in the tooltip the string "fluffy", hopefully along with the image link "path/to/the/image/of/a/cat"? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible AFAICT out of the box. I did something similar here: http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2016/03/21/Displaying-image-overlays-on-image-filenames-in-Emacs/ and modified tooltips on a link here http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2015/11/23/Improving-org-ref-cite-links-with-tooltips/. They might give you some hints on how to get what you want.

Comment: I tried to modified the `image-tooltip-re` to make links like `[[file:./test.png]]` display as tooltip when mouse hover, but it didn't work. The regex look fine though `(setq image-tooltip-re (concat "\\(?:\\[\\[file:\\)\\(?1:.*\\."
                               (regexp-opt '("png" "PNG" "JPG" "jpeg"
                                             "jpg" "JPEG" "eps" "EPS"))
                               "\\)\\(?:\\]\\]\\)"))`. Do you have any suggestion on this?